# Categorized and ordered weapon switching system

Tags: c#

I am creating a weapon switching system for my game. The weapons have specific categories and positions. And players will select them accordingly. Note that positions can be negative too, it just works as an order for which weapons in the category. And currently, there are only 9 categories, and I don't aim to change that in the future.

I will have several functions that will handle the weapon selecting but each of them in a different way:

- Select the next weapon
- Select the previous weapon
- Select the next weapon in a certain category
- Select the specific weapon (which is the easiest one to implement)

I have my categories as a class:

```cs
class WeaponCategory 
{
    Dictionary<int, Weapon> weapons = new Dictionary<int, Weapon>();
}
```

I am using a dictionary at the moment since that was the one I thought would be the most appropriate for what I am doing. Dictionary keys represent the positions of the weapons. I am creating 9 WeaponCategory in my other script as an array, like this:

```
WeaponCategory[] categories = new WeaponCategory[9]
```

Say, I have a Pistol which is positioned at category 1 and position -2, a Shotgun positioned at category 1 and position 3, an SMG positioned at category 2 and position 1. (SMG's position doesn't matter because, in its category, there is only itself). And image the player is currently using the weapon Pistol, so while their current category is 1, their current position is -2. So when I want to select the next weapon (function #1) it should go the Shotgun whose position is higher than the Pistol. And after that, when I am using Shotgun now; if I wanted to select the prev weapon, it should go back to the Pistol again, but instead, if I select the next weapon, it should go to the SMG whose category is higher than that. The actual thing starts from here, imagine I am currently using the SMG which is the highest positioned weapon; if I select the next weapon, it should go to the weapon whose position is the lowest in the hierarchy. Function #2 does pretty much the same thing, except the reverse.

So for function #3, it is going to be a similar one above but it will happen only in the certain category the weapon is located at. Imagine I am using the Pistol if I select the next weapon in the category it will basically go to the Shotgun, and when I am using the Shotgun, and if I do that again, it should go to Pistol.

If you are familiar, that is the same system in the game CS:GO or alike.

It'd be so cool if you guys give me some code to handle that if not, a code block would do too. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you really need it as a separate class if it consist of a single field - a Dictionary?

Comment: It may have other fields and methods that perform small tasks in the future, but this is the way I came up with right now. Maybe you have a different approach to this?

Comment: If anyone's curious, I ended up using SortedLists instead of Dictionaries. It automatically compares the keys and sorts itself accordingly each time a new element added. And if you are doing something similar, use Keys property too, it'll do a lot of things in an easier way.

Comment: If you solved your original question as posted, do not hesitate to post it as a self-answer - while there will be a delay on accepting it as the correct answer, it will still be useful for the community and gain points as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using [SortedLists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netcore-3.1) instead of Dictionaries. SortedLists automatically compares the keys (as long as the keys are common types such as ints, floats; otherwise you'll have to create a IComparer while constructing your SortedList) and sorts itself accordingly each time a new element added.

As cycling in weapon menus, you will have to check whether an element with specific key exists in a loop. For that, you can use [Keys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.keys?view=netcore-3.1) property instead. You will no more need to check if a particular key exists in your list, but you will get the index of the key using IndexOfKey() method and do the rest getting the proper key with Keys property using the index.